# Conversor de XLSX a CSV

Tags: java, csv, xlsx

En el conversor de formatos de archivos .xlsx a .csv necesito que tenga la opción de eliminar la primera fila (que sería el cabecero de la tabla) o de mantenerlo.
He utilizado la librería Apache POI para trabajar con archivos Excel y luego escribir los datos en un archivo CSV.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class XLSXtoCSVConverter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        // Cargar el archivo XLS (Excel)
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("input.xlsx"));
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

        // Crear un archivo CSV de salida
        FileWriter csvFile = new FileWriter("output.csv");

        // Recorrer las hojas del archivo Excel
        for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);

            // Recorrer las filas y columnas para obtener los datos
            for (Row row : sheet) {
                for (Cell cell : row) {
                    csvFile.append(cell.toString());
                    csvFile.append(",");
                }
                csvFile.append("\n");
            }
        }

        // Cerrar el archivo CSV
        csvFile.close();
        System.out.println("Archivo CSV generado exitosamente.");

        // Cerrar el archivo Excel
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Tal como está formulada la pregunta no es claro ¿Cuál es la pregunta o el problema? ¿Qué error aparece?

Comment: Buenas @HeytalePazguato creo que el enunciado es claro "necesito que tenga la opción de eliminar la primera fila (que sería el cabecero de la tabla) o de mantenerlo." Ignoro como indicar esta opción.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes agregar una bandera para la cabecera y por parámetro de args lo leas, con esto la primera lectura está condicionada a que por argumento se escriba, a partir de la segunda siempre se escribirá por el flag cabecera.

```
boolean cabecera = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[0]);
// Recorrer las filas y columnas para obtener los datos
for (Row row : sheet) {
    if (cabecera) {
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            csvFile.append(cell.toString());
            csvFile.append(",");
        }
        csvFile.append("\n");
    }
    cabecera = true;
}
```

Comment: Buenísimo!! Muchas gracias!